# Using variables that contain quotes in a powershell commandlet

Tags: powershell, variables, command

I'm struggling with this for hours, I tried to Google it but using double-quotes, Invoke-Expression or the thinge with @ doesn't help.

```
$SrcLoc = ''
$VMachine = 'computer'
$Paths = @()
$Paths = ('\c$\Users\', '\c$\Program Files\', '\c$\Program Files (x86)\')

foreach ($path in $Paths){
    $SrcLoc += '"\\' + $VMachine + $path + '" ,' 
}
$SrcLoc = $SrcLoc.Substring(0,$SrcLoc.Length-2)
#$CREDENTIALED_SECTION = @{Username=$SrcLoc}
Write-Host $SrcLoc
#Invoke-Expression $SrcLoc
Get-ChildItem $SrcLoc -filter "*google*"  -Directory -Recurse -force  | % { $_.fullname }
```

And the result is:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (3)\chrome2.ps1
"\\computer\c$\Users\" ,"\\computer\c$\Program Files\" ,"\\computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\" 
\\computer\c$\Users\ 
\\computer\c$\Program Files\ 
\\computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\ 

Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path. At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (3)\chrome2.ps1:13 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem $SrcLoc -filter "*google*"  -Directory -Recurse -force  | % { $_.f ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Please Advise 
Thank You

Comment: What's the goal here?  Help me understand the task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to find all Google chrome setup.exe files in whole environment to uninstall it remotely. 
For now $VMachine is just a string but i want to use it as an array in the future to loop over whole environment, search and destroy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just moved some things around and cleaned the syntax a bit, and it works fine :)

As it turns out, you can forget about all of that fancy formatting and make this much easier on yourself, so on the line where you're coming up with the `$SrlLoc`, just move that statement into the ForEach loop and also get the directory contents there.  No need for multiple steps, and you don't need to build an empty array to add items to it (which is what you were doing with `$srcLoc = @()` )

```
$VMachine = 'computer'
$Paths = ('c$\Users\', 'c$\Program Files\', 'c$\Program Files (x86)\')

foreach ($path in $Paths){
   $SrcLoc = "\\$VMachine\$path"
   Write-Output "Searching $srcloc"
   Get-ChildItem $SrcLoc -filter "*google*" -Directory -Recurse -ea SilentlyContinue | 
     select -ExpandProperty FullName
}
```

I moved your `Get-ChildItem` command up into the ForEach loop, to make things cleaner and easier to understand.  As for the syntax of variable contatenation, I really recommend people steer clear of `$something = "sometext" + $SomeObject + (Some-Command).Output`, you're begging for errors when you ask PowerShell to mush things together like that.

The output of the code is this.

```
Searching \\behemoth\c$\Users\
\\behemoth\c$\Users\Stephen\Dropbox\My Code\SCCMBackup\Google Earth
Searching \\behemoth\c$\Program Files\
Searching \\behemoth\c$\Program Files (x86)\
\\behemoth\c$\Program Files (x86)\Google
\\behemoth\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Microsoft Azure\Mobile Services\2.0\Packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.2.1.0
\\behemoth\c$\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Resources\Plug-ins-4ccd2ca\Services.bundle\Contents\Service Sets\com.plexapp.plugins.googledrive
\\behemoth\c$\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Resources\Plug-ins-4ccd2ca\Services.bundle\Contents\Service Sets\com.plexapp.plugins.googledrive\URL\Google Drive
\\behemoth\c$\Program Files (x86)\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\GoogleDrive
```

I added `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the `Get-ChildItem` because you'll run into permissions issues, trying to look at protected directories remotely.  Using `-Ea SilentlyContinue` suppresses those errors.

Comment: Well it looks much better. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I wonder why it works for you and not for me.

_Get-ChildItem \\lonvdysand\c$\Users\ -filter "*google*"  -Directory -Recurse -force -ea SilentlyContinue | % { $_.fullname }_

**\\lonvdysand\c$\Users\YSand\AppData\Local\Google
\\lonvdysand\c$\Users\YSand\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\https_www.google.com_0**

_PS C:\Users\mhoffman> Get-ChildItem \\lonvdysand\c$\Users\ -filter "*google*" -Directory -Recurse -ea SilentlyContinue| select -ExpandProperty FullName_

This returns nothing :(

Thank You

Comment: Make sure you have some directories with Google in the name :). You could also remove the -errorAction SilentlyContinue and see if there are errors which give you a clue.

Comment: Yes i did removed and no errors :/ 
Yes the directories are there first command finds them

Comment: So i replaced your Command with mine old command in your script and it works. I have no clue how its possible with paths that contains spaces and isn't inside "".

Thank You